# Issue with xcode 7.2 while Build and run app on iOS 9.2 device

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, xcode7.2, ios9.2

When ever i build the project xCode shows too many errors like

- Too many errors emitted, stopping now.
- Expected ';' after top level declarator.
- While building module 'CoreFoundation' / 'Foundation' / 'Darwin' imported from /User/mac/Desktop/folder name/project name/AFURLSessionManager.h:22:
- While building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/platforms/iPhoneOS.Platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2sdk/System/Library/Framework/Foundation.Framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6

I am facin this type of errors
can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

I am stuck here.

Help me so i can continue my work please.

Comment: Check your targets for architectures. Make sure you have 'NO' on build only current architectures in release phase. Also check what SDK you are keep referencing too.

Comment: i changed but still this issue remains as it is

Comment: How did u add AFNetworking!? Cocoapods or manually!?

Comment: You have more than Xcode version in Same Mac Mini

Comment: Yes i have 2 Xcode versions in same mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed Old Xcode version from your mac.
Thats it.!!!